# Profile-specific @Configuration class does not work after profile set in application.yaml

Tags: spring

I want to migrate from `application.properties` to `application.yaml` and use profiles and different `@Configuration`-classes per profile.

Expected behavior:
`TestEnvPrinter.printEnv: env = test`

Actual behavior:
`DefaultEnvPrinter.printEnv(): env = default, profile = test`

Why Spring uses only `DefaultAppConfig` and ignores `TestAppConfig` `@Configuration`-class?

Some of app files:

`application.yaml`:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: test
app:
  env: default
```

`application-test.yaml`:

```
app:
  env: test
```

`DefaultAppConfig.java`:

```
@ComponentScan("ru.albert_rayanov")
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yaml")
public class DefaultAppConfig {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer result = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yamlFactory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        yamlFactory.setResources(new ClassPathResource("application.yaml"));
        result.setProperties(Objects.requireNonNull(yamlFactory.getObject()));
        return result;
    }
}
```

`TestAppConfig.java`:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:application-test.yaml")})
public class TestAppConfig {
    @Bean
    public EnvPrinter envPrinter() {
        return new TestEnvPrinter();
    }
}
```

`DefaultEnvPrinter.java`:

```
@Component
@Primary
public class DefaultEnvPrinter implements EnvPrinter {
    @Value("${app.env}")
    private String env;

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String profile;

    @Override
    public void printEnv() {
        System.out.println("DefaultEnvPrinter.printEnv(): env = " + env + ", profile = " + profile);
    }
}
```

`TestEnvPrinter.java`:

```
@Component
public class TestEnvPrinter implements EnvPrinter {

    @Value("${app.env}")
    private String env;

    @Override
    public void printEnv() {
        System.out.println("TestEnvPrinter.printEnv: env = " + env);
    }
}
```

`ProfileWorker.java`:

```
@Component
public class ProfileWorker {
    private final EnvPrinter envPrinter;

    public ProfileWorker(EnvPrinter envPrinter) {
        this.envPrinter = envPrinter;
    }

    public void doWork() {
        envPrinter.printEnv();
    }
}
```

`Main.java`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DefaultAppConfig.class);
        context.getBean(ProfileWorker.class).doWork();
    }
}
```

`pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.albert_rayanov</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring_1_7_profiles</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.33</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: You've tagged your question with `spring-boot` but don't appear to be using Spring Boot. Can you clarify?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson removed `spring-boot` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Framework's `@PropertySource` does not have out-of-the-box support for YAML. It will be treating your YAML file as a `.properties` file and, therefore, failing to find the expected configuration. You can write a custom `PropertySourceFactory` implementation to add YAML support and specify the factory using the `factory` attribute of `@PropertySource`.

As [described in this Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource), the `PropertySourceFactory` implementation is fairly straightforward:

```java
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource encodedResource) throws IOException {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(encodedResource.getResource());
        Properties properties = factory.getObject();
        return new PropertiesPropertySource(encodedResource.getResource().getFilename(), properties);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, which dependency can I use to add support of `PropertySourceFactory`? If I still don't use Spring Boot starters

Comment: You shouldn't need any additional dependencies. `PropertySourceFactory` is part of Spring Framework in its `spring-core` module. You're already using `spring-core` through your dependency on `spring-context`.